# GraphicEx with Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I installed [GraphicEx](http://www.soft-gems.net) (a Delphi image loader library) in Delphi 7, and it worked fine.

Now, when I try to install it in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, I get errors:

```
[dcc32 Error] JPG.pas(1136): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'jpeg_reset_huff_decode' 
[dcc32 Error] JPG.pas(1258): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '@jfwrite'
[dcc32 Error] JPG.pas(1258): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '@jfflush'
[dcc32 Error] JPG.pas(1258): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '@jfread'
[dcc32 Fatal Error] GraphicEx.pas(613): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'JPG.pas'
```

So, how can I use GraphicEx in Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Comment: Any idea how is the speed of GraphicEx compared with classic Delphi way (TImage)? Is it faster?

Comment: @Rigel TImage is faster. If you need more image format (eps for example) you can use GraphicEx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described on the page to which you link, this library has not been updated to the latest versions of Delphi. However, you will most likely find that you do not need it any more. Recent Delphi versions have out of the box support for JPEG and PNG images formats.

Resolve your problem by removing references to this library and using the built in image format support.

If you are using the library for the more esoteric image formats that it offers then you will need to update it to work with the your version of Delphi.

In the first instance, the compilation errors that you report are simply down to your not having added the necessary folders to your search path. The object files that define those functions are found in the `3rd party\LibJPG\obj` folder. You must add that to your search path. When you do that you will get another error. Keep resolving them one by one.

Comment: Out-of-box JPEG support is as recent as 20yo, there were changes... Please rephrase that part - OP is surprised why code fails to link with old IJG.

Comment: I cannot understand that comment

Comment: My goal of using GraphicEx is for supporting other common image format like (*.tif; *.tiff), (*.bw, *.rgb, *.rgba, *.sgi), Autodesk images files (*.cel; *.pic), Kodak Photo-CD images (*.pcd) Photoshop images (*.psd, *.pdd) and more.

Comment: Ok. You'll need to update it to work with your Delphi version then. You started with the latest version from github did you?

Comment: Thanks Mr. David Heffernan for quick reply, I tried to update it but no success, when I googled about I found the same problem mentioned at link: https://github.com/mike-lischke/GraphicEx/issues/9 and no solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You have not configured your project to find all the necessary files.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. David. This help me. I accept your answer.

Comment: New note: there is an update for GraphicEx have been made by Nabbla is almost solve all problems and works very nice. Thanks to Nabbla https://github.com/nabbla/GraphicEx.

Comment: @MarwanAlmukh the Nabbla link is broken, the mike-lischke one still works and it seems he was the original author via soft-gems (the soft-gems download doesn't exist anymore)